# Live monitoring using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'd like to accomplish the following using Apache Beam:

> calculate every 5 seconds the events that are read from pubsub  in the last minute

The goal is to have a semi-realtime view on the rate data comes in. This can then be expanded towards more complex use cases afterwards.

After searching, I've not come across a way to solve this seemingly simple problem. Things that do not work:

- global window + repeated triggers (triggers do not fire when there is no input)
- sliding window + withoutDefaults (does not allow empty windows to be emitted apparently)

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does semi-realtime view  means even there is no data for a window, that window should emit a default value?

Comment: @RuiWang yes, exactly

Comment: For such question, so far what I saw were suggestions around emitting fake data and filtering it out or using state store to save result and does a second computation.

Comment: I also saw these type of answers, but that means beam has the severe limitation that it is impossible to detect missing data, hence also impossible to for example add empty rows to BigQuery when no Data is found?

Comment: My understanding is that's not limitation and those data are not missing data. The exactly-once semantic means Beam running on runners should not lose state on "seen" data. Windows that do not have data means Beam never sees those data.

Comment: Of course, but responding on windows without data (eg fixed ones) makes sense in a lot of scenarios, no?

Comment: Yes it should be useful if somehow provided. Does any system with similar steaming windowing design provide semi-realtime view?

Comment: I’m not sure. Just getting started with these specific use cases :)

Comment: I see. It would require some decent amount work to provide this feature in Beam. Basically to provide that Beam need runners' support to save state of windowing assignment and automatic inference missing windows, combing with trigger and watermark to emit result. I don't think this feature will be prioritized in the near feature.

Comment: Ok, so a forever trigger on a global window is not necessarily forever? It can only fire after at least one event and will stop after it?

Comment: Also, watermarks of empty windows that are passed could easily be detected when the next one closes, no? It also seems like threshold detection on number events is made impossible due to this limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already discussed, Beam does not emit data for empty windows. In addition to the reasons given by Rui Wang we can add the challenge of how the latter stages would handle those empty panes.

Anyway, the specific use case that you describe -monitoring rolling count of number of messages - should be possible with some work even if the metric falls down to zero eventually. One possibility would be to publish a steady number of dummy messages which would advance the watermark and fire the panes but are filtered out later within the pipeline. The problem with this approach is that the publishing source needs to be adapted and that might not always be convenient/possible. Another one would involve generating this fake data as another input and co-group it with the main stream. The advantage is that everything can be done in Dataflow without the need to tweak the source or the sink. To illustrate this I provide an example.

The inputs are divided in two streams. For the dummy one, I used `GenerateSequence` to create a new element every 5 seconds. I then window the PCollection (windowing strategy needs to be compatible with the one for the main stream so I will use the same). Then I map the element to a key-value pair where the value is 0 (we could use other values as we know from which stream the element comes but I want to evince that dummy records are not counted).

```java
PCollection<KV<String,Integer>> dummyStream = p
    .apply("Generate Sequence", GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
    .apply("Window Messages - Dummy", Window.<Long>into(
            ...
    .apply("Count Messages - Dummy", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, KV<String, Integer>>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            c.output(KV.of("num_messages", 0));
        }
    }));
```

For the main stream, that reads from Pub/Sub, I map each record to value 1. Later on, I will add all the ones as in typical word count examples using map-reduce stages.

```java
PCollection<KV<String,Integer>> mainStream = p
    .apply("Get Messages - Data", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic))
    .apply("Window Messages - Data", Window.<String>into(
            ...
    .apply("Count Messages - Data", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String, Integer>>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            c.output(KV.of("num_messages", 1));
        }
    }));
```

Then we need to join them using a `CoGroupByKey` (I used the same `num_messages` key to group counts). This stage will output results when one of the two inputs has elements, therefore unblocking the main issue here (empty windows with no Pub/Sub messages).

```java
final TupleTag<Integer> dummyTag = new TupleTag<>();
final TupleTag<Integer> dataTag = new TupleTag<>();

PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(dummyTag, dummyStream)
        .and(dataTag, mainStream).apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());
```

Finally, we add all the ones to obtain the total number of messages for the window. If there are no elements coming from `dataTag` then the sum will just default to 0.

```java
public void processElement(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window) {
    Integer total_sum = new Integer(0);

    Iterable<Integer> dataTagVal = c.element().getValue().getAll(dataTag);
    for (Integer val : dataTagVal) {
        total_sum += val;
    }

    LOG.info("Window: " + window.toString() + ", Number of messages: " + total_sum.toString());
}
```

This should result in something like: [image]

Note that results from different windows can come unordered (this can happen anyway when writing to BigQuery) and I did not play with the window settings to optimize the example.

Full code:

```java
public class EmptyWindows {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmptyWindows.class);

    public static interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {
        @Description("Input topic")
        String getInput();

        void setInput(String s);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        String topic = options.getInput();

        PCollection<KV<String,Integer>> mainStream = p
            .apply("Get Messages - Data", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic))
            .apply("Window Messages - Data", Window.<String>into(
                    SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                            .every(Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
                    .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                    .accumulatingFiredPanes())
            .apply("Count Messages - Data", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String, Integer>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                    //LOG.info("New data element in main output");
                    c.output(KV.of("num_messages", 1));
                }
            }));

        PCollection<KV<String,Integer>> dummyStream = p
            .apply("Generate Sequence", GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
            .apply("Window Messages - Dummy", Window.<Long>into(
                    SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                            .every(Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
                    .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                    .accumulatingFiredPanes())
            .apply("Count Messages - Dummy", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, KV<String, Integer>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                    //LOG.info("New dummy element in main output");
                    c.output(KV.of("num_messages", 0));
                }
            }));

        final TupleTag<Integer> dummyTag = new TupleTag<>();
        final TupleTag<Integer> dataTag = new TupleTag<>();

        PCollection<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> coGbkResultCollection = KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(dummyTag, dummyStream)
                .and(dataTag, mainStream).apply(CoGroupByKey.<String>create());

        coGbkResultCollection
                .apply("Log results", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, Void>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window) {
                        Integer total_sum = new Integer(0);

                        Iterable<Integer> dataTagVal = c.element().getValue().getAll(dataTag);
                        for (Integer val : dataTagVal) {
                            total_sum += val;
                        }

                        LOG.info("Window: " + window.toString() + ", Number of messages: " + total_sum.toString());
                    }
                }));

        p.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guillem Xercavins! I learned a lot from your answer. I didn't think about dummy stream in Beam directly. This probably the most convenient and easy approach.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I didn't know you could generate data this way. This will solve a lot of my questions! Will try it out asap. The fact that the results of different windows come unordered: what do you mean that this can happen anyway when writing to BQ?

Comment: A follow-up question: this does not work if you do a group by key I assume, as you would not to make sure all those dummy events end up with all the keys. Correct?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Regarding BigQuery, I mean that there is no order guarantee for rows returned in a query unless you use ORDER BY. In my example, you can order by window to have ordered results. I think the example can be extended to use GBK too, either with "nested" KVs or assigning keys after the CoGroupByKey. It will depend on the exact use case.

Comment: @GuillemXercavins what is GBK?

Comment: @Jonny5 It's just the short for "Group By Key". Another possibility would be to yield a dummy event for each key. Of course, this can only work if you know all possible keys a priori (and number is relatively small)

Comment: @GuillemXercavins thanks, exactly, and in our case they are limited, but can slowly grow over time.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this problem is using a stateful `DoFn` with a looping `Timer` that triggers at each 5 second tick. This looping timer generates the default data necessary for the live monitoring, and ensures that each window has at least one event to process.

One issue with the approach described by https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543527/430128 is that, in a system with multiple keys, these "dummy" events need to be generated for every key.

See https://beam.apache.org/blog/looping-timers/. Option 1 and 2 in that article are an external heartbeat source and a generated source in the beam pipeline respectively. Option 3 is the looping timer.